# cannot click items echoed by another page using ajax - $(document).on is not working

Tags: php, jquery

> > updated

i'm having 2 pages. An index page connected to a js file. This js file containing ajax code fetching data from database. 
this is my js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // getting links from db andshow sub_menu div //
    $(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("selected").children().slideDown(500,function(){
            var id = $(".selected").attr("id");
            var ajax= false;
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var qst = "?id="+id;
            ajax.open("GET","ajax/get_sub_cats.php"+qst);
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
                    $(".sub_menu[title="+id+"]").html(ajax.responseText);
                }
            }
            ajax.send(null);
        });
    });

    // hiding sub_menu div //
    $(".menu_item").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("selected").children(".sub_menu").slideUp(500);
    });

    // keeping sub_menu div visible on mouse over //
    $(".sub_menu").mouseover(function() {
        $(this).stop();
    });

    // clicking sub menu link in the menu //
    $(document).delegate("a#subCatLink","click",function(){
    alert("test");
    }); 
    // document ready end
    });
```

and this is get_sub_cats php file used to fetch links from db

```
<?php
require('../_req/base.php');
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$getSubcatsQ = "select * from sub_cats where Main_Cat_ID = '$id'";
$getSubcatsR = mysql_query($getSubcatsQ);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($getSubcatsR);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getSubcatsR)){
    ?>
   <a id="subCatLink" href="products.php?id=<?php echo $row['Sub_Cat_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Sub_Cat_Name']; ?></a><br />
    <?php
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

clicking links coming from the other php file using ajax is not working at all

Comment: I don't see the Ajax. The picture is also unclear; it sounds like you're including JS to do Ajax to do an include; why not just use PHP from end-to-end for the HTML rendering portion? Finally, it looks like you're trying to use an ID (`#subCatLink`) as a class, though it's hard to say from this abbreviated code sample. If more than one anchor has `#subCatLink` you are doing it wrong, as there can only be one instance of an ID per page.

Comment: I think something in your problem description is missing: your fiddle does NOT contain the above click event manager as it should.  +1 to what @Greg Pettit said.

Comment: i mean jsfiddle code displays the .stop() to keep the sub_menu visible so you can tell if it's the problem or not

Comment: You're already using jQuery... you should use the `$.ajax()` method! Ajax abstraction and event binding are the two best reasons to be using jQuery (not animations); so why ignore that part of the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, maybe this will help, maybe not. But...

Why don't you use something like this:

jQuery

```
$(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){   
    var id = $(".selected").attr("id");
    var qst = "?id="+id;
    var html = '';
    $.getJSON('ajax/get_sub_cats.php'+qst, function(data){
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<a id="subCatLink'+data[i].Sub_Cat_ID+'" href="products.php?id='+data[i].Sub_Cat_ID+'">'+data[i].Sub_Cat_Name+'</a>';
        }
        $(".sub_menu[id="+id+"]").html(html);
    });
});
```

PHP

```
require('../_req/base.php');
$return = array();

$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = "select * from sub_cats where Main_Cat_ID = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $return[] = $ln;
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: PS: I put an ID on your 'a tag id' because you should not (dom is not pleased) have 2 elements or more with the same id

Answer (score -1):

ok try this

```
$(document).delegate("click","a",function(){ 
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
    alert(target); 
});
```

That should, as a test, show the href for every link on your page. If that works, put all the links you want to show in a div. Then call it with

```
$('#divID').delegate("click","a",function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("href"); 
    alert(target); 
})
```

Comment: What do you mean "has been suspended"? It's only in 1.7+, so you may be right that it's not available to Yasser... but "suspended" makes it sound like it has been dropped.

Comment: Haha you're quite right, I totally miss-read what was on api.jQuery.com It's been a long day :-/

Comment: jquery 1.7.1 and still not working with .delegate and i guess it should be like this $(document).delegate("a#subCatLink",click",function(){
as i found out on jquery website but still not working

Comment: you're creating loads of a links with the same ID. ID's need to be unique.

Comment: now the sub_menu id changed to title and has the same value of the menu_item id no more double ids.but nothing happens at all on clicking links in the sub_menu div

Comment: ok try this $(document).delegate("click","a",function(){
   var target = $(this).attr("href");
   alert(target);  
});

Comment: That should, as a test, show the href for every link on your page. If that works, put all the links you want to show in a div. Then call it with $('#divID').delegate("click","a",function(){ var target = $(this).attr("href"); alert(target); })

Comment: thanks all now i did it using just php not exactly as i wanted with jq but at least it'll work thanks again