# Get jQuery slider values from DB

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a database with these tables

```
company
==========
id | name |
==========
 1 | C1   |
 2 | C2   |
 3 | C3   |

 position
 =================
id | level | name |
==================
 1 |  1    | SE   |
 2 |  2    | SE1  | 
 3 |  3    | SE2  |
 4 |  1    | SA   |
 5 |  2    | SA1  |
 3 |  3    | SA2  |

 company_position
 ==========
 cid | pid |
 ==========
  1  |  1  |
  1  |  2  |
  1  |  3  |
  2  |  1  |
  2  |  2  |
  2  |  3  |
  3  |  1  |
  3  |  2  |
  3  |  3  |
```

In the UI, I have a `<select>` for displaying Company names. There is a corresponsding slider that should display Position range. onChange on the `<select>`, I would like the slider the receive new values for range (min, max, name of Position instead of value). How do I go about solving this? jQuery getJSON? I am not looking for code, rather an approach!

**UPDATE**
I realized that my problem is that I am unable to imagine the structure of JSON callback data.

Comment: yes i think the best solution will be saving your database values into some JSON object and use it to set the options for the slider. is there any specific question?

Comment: @ggzone noob question: is there a way to query JSON object based on a company ID? I guess I am struggling to make the JSON object queriable.

Comment: look into the synthax of JSON objects... its like an array. you have your object like "company", "position" with your id and its values. you can use it after that for loops or whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you do a `$.post` to your server, with the selected company. Let's say the user selected company 1. Then, on the server, you want to a query like:

```
SELECT position.level, position.name FROM position
JOIN company_position ON position.id = company_position.pid
JOIN company ON company.id = company_position.cid
WHERE company.id = ?
```

Now, you should have a result set with `(1, SE), (2, SE1), (3, SE2)` given your data above. I would send this back as a JSON object (I don't know what server environment you have, so building this structure is up to you):

```
{
  "min": 1,
  "max": 3,
  "positions": {
    "1": "SE",
    "2": "SE1",
    "3": "SE2"
  }
}
```

Alternately, if there are few positions, you could let the client calculate max and min, just sending JSON:

```
{
  "1": "SE",
  "2": "SE1",
  "3": "SE2"
}
```

And calculating max, min with javascript:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(null, Object.keys(response))
  , min = Math.min.apply(null, Object.keys(response));
```

In your javascript, given the object

```
var result = {
  "min": 1,
  "max": 3,
  "positions": {
    "1": "SE",
    "2": "SE1",
    "3": "SE2"
  }
};
```

You can query that object like this: `positions["1"] == "SE"`. So, if you want to show the labels for min and max, you would find the values for min and max like so:

```
var min = result.min, max = result.max
```

And you find their labels like this:

```
var minLabel = result.positions[result.min]
  , maxLabel = result.positions[result.max];
```

Comment: once I have the data, should I again loop (`$.each(data, function(key, val) {`) and put them in a 2D array? Or, is there a way to directly read a value by passing a key?

Answer (score 2):

I would go the AJAX way, just have your onChange call a jQuery POST function that passes the `<select>` value (so you can filter properly), and anything else you need.
And then on callback, you'll recieve the desired values properly encoded (json_encode is an option) for reading or just in plain text.
But remember the `data` from the callback function is just **one** variable, if you need more (e.g. minium and maxium values), encode the desired data so you can access it later

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296306/cannot-click-items-echoed-by-another-page-using-ajax-document-on-is-not-wor/9297078#9297078) a couple of minutes ago. Maybe this will help, maybe not.

Why don't you use something like this:

jQuery

```
$(".menu_item").mouseover(function(){   
    var id = $(".selected").attr("id");
    var qst = "?id="+id;
    var html = '';
    $.getJSON('ajax/get_sub_cats.php'+qst, function(data){
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<a id="subCatLink'+data[i].Sub_Cat_ID+'" href="products.php?id='+data[i].Sub_Cat_ID+'">'+data[i].Sub_Cat_Name+'</a>';
        }
        $(".sub_menu[id="+id+"]").html(html);
    });
});
```

PHP

```
 require('../_req/base.php');
    $return = array();

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $sql = "select * from sub_cats where Main_Cat_ID = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($ln = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $return[] = $ln;
    }

    echo json_encode($return);
```

As shown in the sample (PHP, but you can do some other like serialization on asp.net) I use json_encode.